# При валидации формы запомнить значения checkbox и select

Tags: java, spring, jsp, form

При валидации, когда происходит ошибка введенных данных, страница перезагружается.
Данные в checkbox и select сбрасываются на стандартные, а у полей input введенный текст сохраняется.

Как сохранить значения в checkbox и select?

```
<form:input path="email" id="emailInput" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          value=""
                          maxlength="50"/>

<form:select path="age" id="ageList" name="age" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Age</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
</form:select>

<form:checkbox path="emailVisibility" name="emailVisibility" id="emailVisibilityInput"
                               class="form-check-input"
                               checked="checked"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо html-тега `<option>` используйте тег Spring'а - `<form:option>`

```
<form:select path="age" id="ageList" name="age" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="0">Age</option>
    <form:option value="16">16</option>
    <form:option value="18">18</option>
</form:select>
```

С чекбоксом, на сколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что он будучи сброшенным устанавливается обратно? Попробуйте не использовать атрибут `checked`.